# React.js controlled components using nested states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**The problem:**
How can I update the nested states from [data] from my form without any errors. The way I'm doing it right now works, but it throws me an error in the console. What is the correct way to update a nested state from a form.

*I know that data is initialized empty and it's simply because it is set when the page load with useEffect.*

**The code:**

```
 const [data, setData] = useState({});

    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
            required
            placeholder="Enter title"
            value={data?.title}
            onChange={(e) => setData({...data, title: e.target.value})}
        />
        {formError?.title?.length > 0 ? <Form.Label className="text-danger">{formError?.title}</Form.Label> : null}
    </Form.Group>
```

Comment: make initial data as empty array, btw what all are the properties of data ?

Comment: _but it throws me an error in the console._ <-- what is the error thrown? Would you please share to help investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React will treat this as uncontrolled component, because the `value` attribute  is `undefined` initially and you are setting it to `string` on Change of `value`.

For uncontrolled inputs we won't pass the `value` attribute. If we don't pass any attribute it is considered as `undefined`. Here you are confusing react by first setting it to `undefined` and later with some value. That's why you are getting `changing from uncontrolled to controlled input` warning.

Provide default value in state to use it as a controlled input.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({title: ""});
```

or `value={data?.title || ""}`

See more of [controlled/uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#:%7E:text=In%20a%20controlled%20component%2C%20form,form%20values%20from%20the%20DOM.)

Comment: Is it recommended to always provide default values or is the second option your provided good enough.

Comment: Both are fine in this case, second option will fallback to `""` if  `data.title` is undefined/null([falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values). It is actually a good approach to provide a default value for state, if you already knew the properties of the state object.

Comment: Oh ok, I just didn't want to put them since it would add a lot of lines, but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks you again!